# Windows narrator is not reading the custom tooltip content?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, uwp-xaml, windows-community-toolkit, automationpeer

I have a requirement to read the content of complex tooltip content for WPF or UWP application by narrator. I am facing challenge to read the content visible for tooltip. Have tried to override the AutomationPeer class and there methods. But no luck :(

My XAML UI is below:

```
 <Button Content="Submit" Grid.Row="2" Height="100" Width="200"  >
        <Button.ToolTip  x:Uid="Addition_Details" > 
            <local:MyStackPanel Orientation="Vertical"  Focusable="True" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="0" ForceCursor="True">
                <TextBlock Text="Additional Details" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Driver" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="2"/>
                <TextBlock Text="A0221" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="3"/>
            </local:MyStackPanel>
        </Button.ToolTip>
    </Button>
```

CustomGrid class is like:

```
 public class MyStackPanel:StackPanel
{
    protected override AutomationPeer OnCreateAutomationPeer()
    {
        return new UIAutomationChildPeer(this);
    }

  
}
public class UIAutomationChildPeer : FrameworkElementAutomationPeer
{
    public UIAutomationChildPeer(FrameworkElement element):base(element)
    {

    }

    protected override string GetClassNameCore()
    {
        return "Additional Details";
    }
    protected override List<AutomationPeer> GetChildrenCore()
    {
        var childrenAutomationPeer = new List<AutomationPeer>();

        var owner = Owner as StackPanel;

        if (owner != null)
        {
            //owner.GotFocus += Owner_GotFocus;
            var childElements = owner.Children;// indName("myGrid", owner) as Grid;
            if (childElements != null && childElements.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (TextBlock item in childElements)
                {
                        var headerTextBlockAutomationPeer = new TextAutomationPeer(item);
                    childrenAutomationPeer.Add(headerTextBlockAutomationPeer);

                }
            }

        }

        return childrenAutomationPeer;
        
    }
}

public class TextAutomationPeer : TextBlockAutomationPeer
{
    private StringBuilder detail = new StringBuilder();
    public UIElement Element { get { return Owner; } }

    public TextAutomationPeer(TextBlock owner) : base(owner)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(owner.Text.ToString()))
        {
            detail.Append(owner.Text.ToString());
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return detail.ToString();
    }

}
```

Have tried with manually triggering the focus event or setting Tab Index. Nothing brings out the result. Any leads for resolving this issue.

#UWP #WPF #Windows10

Comment: I noticed that you are using `Button.ToolTip`, so that's a WPF project. right?

Comment: That's absolutely right @RoyLi-MSFT. But, I need to fix UWP as well for the same issue.

Comment: Is my answer helpful to you?

Answer (score 0):

The controls that you put in the tooltip won't get focused so the narrator won't respond to them. This is the same for `TextBlock`.

Generally, we will use the [AutomationProperties.HelpText Attached Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.automation.automationproperties.helptext?view=winrt-22000) to add simple text to a control. The narrator will respond to the `AutomationProperties.HelpText`.